# Image missing with an Error: Cannot set header after they are sent to client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, model-view-controller, file-upload

I converted my old Demo project to MVC style by separating model, view & control, added a new controller folder. All functionalities are working perfectly fine, except the storing of an image. I am getting an error: `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

I did some debugging & found out ***image is present during validation, but it is not present when it is sent to request handler*** to store the db object. [Please check this image of debugging output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMs4X.png)

There is also a strange error in the DB. **title, body & image path** is getting inserted two times inside DB. I deleted the old stuff & tried it again & again. But still noticed, for one insertion using *'/posts/new'* page: two same objects is getting stored in mongodb.  [Image attached from Mongo DB compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDY3C.png)

Here is the project flow: The request object with the  image is picked from '/posts/new' page, validated in the validation middleware, if  title & image are present: it will be sent to the request handler `app.post('/posts/store', storePostController);` which will store the image using path & it will store a mongo db document which contains title, body & image path inside the DB.

The code for the following is given below:
**1) createPost.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- Header-->
<%- include('layouts/header'); -%>

    <body>
        <!-- Navigation-->
        <%- include('layouts/navbar'); -%>
            <!-- Page Header-->
            <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('/assets/img/contact-bg.jpg')">
                <div class="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5">
                    <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                            <div class="page-heading">
                                <h1>Create New Post</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <!-- Main Content-->
            <main class="mb-4">
                <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                    <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                            <div class="my-5">
                                <form action="/posts/store" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <div class="form-floating">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="title" name="title" type="text"
                                            placeholder="Enter the title..." />
                                        <label for="title">Title</label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-floating">
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="body" name="body" style="height: 12rem"
                                            placeholder="Enter your message here..." style="height: 12rem"></textarea>
                                        <label for="message">Description</label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-floating">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="image" name="image" type="file"
                                            placeholder="Upload an image" />
                                        <label for="title">Image</label>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Submit Button-->
                                    <button id="submitButton" type="submit">Send</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
            <!-- Footer-->
            <%- include('layouts/footer'); -%>
                <!-- Scripts-->
                <%- include('layouts/scripts'); -%>
    </body>

</html>
```

**2) index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
//const { resourceUsage } = require('process');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database', { useNewUrlParser: true }); //Defining a connection

const app = new express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const validateMiddleware = require('./middleware/validationMiddleware');
const homeController = require('./controllers/home');
const getPostController = require('./controllers/getPost');
const newPostController = require('./controllers/newPost');
const storePostController = require('./controllers/storePost');


app.use(express.static('public'));  
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(fileUpload());
app.use('/posts/store', validateMiddleware);


app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('App listening on port 4000');
});


app.get('/', homeController);

app.get('/post/:id', getPostController);

app.get('/posts/new', newPostController);

app.post('/posts/store', storePostController);
```

**3) validationMiddleware.js**

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {

    console.log("Executing Validation Middleware")  //Debugging code
    console.log(req.files)                          //Debugging code

    if (req.files == null || req.body.title == "") {

        return res.redirect('/posts/new');
    }
    next();
}
```

**4) storePost.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const BlogPost = require('../models/BlogPost');

module.exports = async (req, res) => {

    let image = req.files.image;

    console.log("Image Name: " + image.name);           //Debugging Code
    console.log("Printing Image : " + req.files.image); //Debugging Code

    image.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/img', image.name),
        async (error) => {
            await BlogPost.create({
                ...req.body,
                image: '/img/' + image.name
            })
            res.redirect('/');
        });

}
```

5. **Folder Structure**
   [Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obdph.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was, I was operating **storePost.js** from the controllers folder & I had copied the code from **index.js** which was in the root folder.

path.resolve() method was expecting one up folder & ***we had to pass an additional argument as '..' after __dirname***

Observe the arguments supplied for path.resolve() method. The below code is the correct way to do it:

```
image.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public/img', image.name),
        async (error) => {
            await BlogPost.create({
                ...req.body,
                image: '/img/' + image.name
            })
            res.redirect('/');
        });
```

One small mistake gave a whole lot of errors, which I couldn't trace. Finally the error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try console req.files in the controller too instead of req.files.image once the debug again also try to convert validation to function() , export it and call it in the controller and use callbacks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @aman Both req.files & req.files.image is giving the same response in both the places. On validator image exists, when it reaches 'request handler' image is missing only other details exist..!

Comment: @aman, validation is indeed a function in a separate .js file, i have exported it & using it in the main controller

Comment: @aman: in non MVC style on my index.js code is working absolutely fine. Only on MVC style it is giving me an error. Issue is not with the validation, issue is with storePost function. I double verified it by toggling with the code...!